# API response is not accessible in ComponentDidMount but in render I can use

Tags: react-native

Hi I am working on React Native app. I am using Redux and Saga. I call the API in componentDidMount.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let data = this.props.navigation.getParam("returnProductData");
    if (data) {
      console.log("Return Here");
      this.props.getProductReturnAction(data)
      this.setState({
        returnQty:parseInt(this.props.product.item_ordered)-parseInt(this.props.product.already_return_qty)
      });
      console.log(this.state.returnQty,"Return quty"); //coming undefined
      console.log(this.props.product, "product"); // undefined
      console.log(this.props.product.item_ordered); //undefined
    }
  }
```

I have to set the state in componentDidMount for returnQty. But, state is not accessible here. It's working fine in render method. I can use all the product object. But, it is coming empty in componentDidMount. I tried using async and await but it's not working.

// Dispatch Methods

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    { getProductReturnAction, submitProductReturnAction },
    dispatch
  );
};
```

// Props

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    product: state.myOrdersReducer.returnProduct
  };
};
```

I can't be able to find out the bug please help to find out the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making API calls through redux/saga, you can not use async await, as the frameworks will just dispatch an action and return back, the listeners which are registered for the action will be triggered and then after they complete their work they will dispatch a new action and respect reducer will handle the response.

Explained above is general scenario.

In your scenario,

- You are dispatching the action returned by `getProductReturnAction` which will give say `GET_PRODUCTS` action.
- A saga would be registered for `GET_PRODUCTS`, say getProducts, this get invoked.
- This will perform the API call once the response is received it will dispatch `GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` along with the products data.
- Corresponding reducer which handles `GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` will get called and that updates `returnProduct` and as you are registered for that in your component the render method gets called (as the props are changed) and hence product data is available in your render method.

This is working perfectly correct. I don't see anything wrong here.

As the data is available in props use the same u do not need to do a setState again on that.

Comment: Actually, I have to show the remaining qty in textbox. So, user will enter the return qty from there. When user enter the value it is set in the state returnQty. So, I need to set the state initially to show the available quantities to users from API response.

Comment: You will get remaining quantity from the API `getProductReturnAction` ?

Comment: Yes I am getting. But, initially I have to set it in the same state of returnQty so that I can use.

Comment: If you are getting if from `getProductReturnAction` api then u can show initially you have to show progress bar until u get response then show the quantity in the text box, there is no other go.